# Rails link_to action, post with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I tried doing several searches for this and couldn't find anything, so hopefully I'm not posting a duplicate.

So, the [API Dock's link_to docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) has this as a signature:

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

Seemed kind of interesting so I decided to give this a shot:

```
<%= link_to { action: 'win', game_id: @games[0].id }, { :method => :post } do %>
  <div>
    <%= image_tag @games[0].img_url %>
    <%= @games[0].name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This resulted in a syntax error in the first line:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
...ffer.append=  link_to { action: 'win', game_id: @games[0].id...
```

I also tried it with parentheses:

```
<%= link_to ({ action: 'win', game_id: @games[0].id }, { :method => :post }) do %>
```

This also gave me a syntax error, same line:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...'win', game_id: @games[0].id }, { :method => :post }) do @ou...
```

I've been looking at this for a while and I figure it's something simple I missed, but if anyone has any idea, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: try `{ :action => 'win', :game_id => @games[0].id }, { :method => :post }`

I'm not sure, but I think it may be because you are mixing 1.9 ruby syntax with <1.9 syntax, that is :key => :value vs key: 'value

Comment: @toolz I tried it but no luck to be found...

Comment: @kotakotakota why don't you use a named route instead of `action: 'win', game_id: @games[0].id`; for example, `won_game_path(id)`?

Comment: @Mohamad No good reason. You're right, that would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! It was the space between the `link_to` and the `(`...